# Symfony, doctrine: Load old values of an entity that is changed via a form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

Using symfony 3.4 (php). I have a form to edit an entity. On saving the changes, I want to manually check which fields have changed to send a change-report to the owner of the entity.

The entity with the changes is provided as parameter of the method. When I load the entity from database via

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MyEntity::class)->find($entity->getId());
```

I get an entity that already has all the changes of the entity provided via the method. Why is that so? How can I load the old entity to compare?

Answer (score 1):

You could check https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/events.html for get the changes before to persist and compare them.

Comment: If you provide a link, it might be better to directly link to the Version of the documentation that is for the symfony Version provided in the question.